# Hover effect not working on submenu but working on other menus?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying  to give hover effect to .login-2-submenu a background effect on all li tags but not effecting at all , tried all possible methods. i tried to give ul to class but not worked i also tried to classs in li not worked as well ,

Am I missing something?

here is my html code

```
 <nav>
            <ul class="flex">
                <li class="px-2"> <input class="searchbox px-2" type="search" name="search"
                        placeholder="Search for products, brands and more" autocomplete="off"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                </li>
                <li class="btn-li px-2"> <button><a href="">Login</a></button>
                    <div class="login-submenu">
                        <div class="login1-1-submenu">
                            <h4>New Customer?</h4>
                            <a class="black" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-2-submenu">

                            <ul>
                                <l1 class="block px border"><a class="black" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>My
                                        Profile</a></l1>
                                <l1 class="block px border"><a class="black" href=""><i
                                            class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>Flipkart Plus Zone</a></l1>
                                <l1 class="block px border"><a class="black" href=""><i
                                            class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i>Orders</a></l1>
                                <l1 class="block px border"><a class="black" href=""><i
                                            class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>Wishlist</a></l1>
                                <l1 class="block px border"><a class="black" href=""><i
                                            class="fa-solid fa-circle-dollar-to-slot"></i>Rewards</a></l1>
                                <l1 class="block px border"><a class="black" href=""><i
                                            class="fa-solid fa-gift"></i>Gift Cards</a></l1>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li class="px-4"> <a href="" class="text">Become a Seller</a></li>
                <li class="px-4 toggle"> <a href="" class="text">More</a>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>Notification Preferances</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i>24/7 Customer Care</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-trend-up"></i>Advertise</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-download"></i>Download App</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                </li>
                <li class="px-5"> <a href="" class="text cart"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>Cart</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and css

```
.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 170px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
}
.sub-menu ul {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sub-menu ul li {
  padding: 15.3px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d9d4;
}

.sub-menu .fa-solid {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #2874f0;
}

.sub-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ebf2f0;
}
.sub-menu ul li a {
  color: black;
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------login-submenu---------------------------------------------- */

.login-submenu {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 465px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  height: 345px;
  width: 250px;
}

.login-submenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.login-submenu .fa-solid {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #2874f0;
}

.sign {
  color: blue !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transform: translate(160px, 0);
}

.login-submenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #28cf8c !important;
}

.login1-1-submenu {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d9d4;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.login1-1-submenu h4 {
  color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.9);
}
.login1-1-submenu a {
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.login1-1-submenu:hover {
  background-color: #ebf2f0;
}

.login-2-submenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ebf2f0 !important;
}
```

I'm tried to give hover effect to login-2-submenu but not working but other hover effect are working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<l1 class="block px border">` just look this code, you have typed `l1` instead of `li`

all `li` tags are misspelled in under `.login-2-submenu`